# A timeline example in HTML+CSS like Facebook's timeline

Tags: html, css, facebook

I'm trying to create a timeline similar to Facebook's timeline, i.e. I want a timeline with two columns where I can place elements on the left and on the right.

In order to do so, I started with the following code but it does not work as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Test 123</li>
      <li style="float:left">Foobar</li>
      <li>Another test</li>
    </ul> /*This line was missing*/
  </body>
</html>
```

The element in the middle is not displayed on the left beside that, the last element floats into the middle one.

Has someone an idea how to create a timeline similar to facebooks one?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the HTML and CSS of the Facebook timeline itself, using a tool such as the IE Developer Tools or Firebug?

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/facebook-timeline-design-using-jquery.html

Comment: @Richard Any sane person shouldn't even consider going near the Facebook HTML. It is truly _truly_ awful.

Answer (score 3):

Seems a pretty straight forward solution to me! Just shove that in your editor. Anymore help just ask

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<style>
body {
    margin:0px;
}
.wrap {
    width:600px;
    height:100%px;
    background:grey;
    margin:auto;
}
.left{
    margin-left:0px;
    width:290px;
    height:200;
    background-color:blue;
}
.right {
    margin-left:310px;
    width:290px;
    height:200;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="wrap">

    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to style it just learn how to do css shapes

```
.right {
   width: 290px; 
   height: 300px; 
   margin-left:315px;
   background: purple;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 2px; 
   border-radius: 2px;
}
.right:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 7px solid transparent;
   border-right: 10px solid purple;
   border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
   margin: 13px 0 0 -10px;
}
```

Comment: I also would like to add a vertical line with bullets for each entry on the left/right as it is done in facebooks timeline. Isn't that easier todo with the ul/li elements? Or the other way around, how would you do it in your solution?

Comment: Do you want me to just basically copy the facebook timeline

Comment: @Stefan I have added a style. Just learn how to do some shapes in css. It's quite straight forward. This is just a static way to do this. If you want to learn a dynamic way you will have to get javascript to do so from this website http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/facebook-timeline-design-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 2):

facebook designers use the following strategy:

```
<ol>
   <li class="twoCol" data-side="l|r">
          your box
      <i></i>
   </li>
</ol>
```

the looks like

```
LI {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2; 
}

 LI[data-side="l"] {
    clear: left;
    float: left; 
}

LI[data-side="r"] {
    clear: right;
    float: right; 
}

.twoCol[data-side="l"] I {
     background-image: url("...");
     background-position: -790px -4px;
}
.twoCol[data-side="r"] I {
    background-image: url("...");
    background-position: -770px -4px;
}

.twoCol I {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto auto;
    left: auto;
    right: -18px; 
}

I {
    height: 15px;
    left: -18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 19px;
    z-index: 3; 
}

.twoCol[data-side="l"] + .twoCol[data-side="r"] > I, 
.twoCol[data-side="r"] + .twoCol[data-side="l"] > I {
    top: 40px; 
}
```

I explains how it works [here](http://www.portablehtml.com/2012/09/how-to-build-facebook-timeline-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

there is a Javascript tool for creating timline check it out http://timeline.verite.co/

Comment: Since I want a very basic/lightwight solution, I do not want to make use of JS.